# How to write ı (i without dot) character in pgf-pie

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, characters, extended-characters

`\i` uses count function instead of showing "ı" character.
Tried `\i`, `{\i}` `$$\i$$`, `\imath` `\text{\i}` but continues to count.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{needspace} %sayfa sonu boşluklarını ayarlamak için
\usepackage[section]{placeins} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{                    
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}  
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} %piechart için
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\newcommand{\sekil}[1]{(Şekil \ref{fig:#1})}
\newcommand{\tablo}[1]{(Tablo \ref{tab:#1})}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\shorthandoff{;}}

%---------------------- Header -------------------------------%
\fancyhead[L]{R. Özgür ALTUN}
\fancyhead[R]{Tangonun Sosyal Dansçıları}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}  
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{26pt}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.9]
\inputencoding{utf8}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
    \pie[sum=auto, text=legend, color={black!0, black!10, black!30, black!50, black!80}, explode=0.1, scale font, before number= {\%}]{9/Doğru veya yanliş olduğunu umursamadan keyif almak, 11/Çalişilan bir eş ile yapmak, 26/Hatali da olsa akici{\i}   yapmak, 2/Keyif almak, 51/Mükemmel şekilde yapana kadar tekrar etmiş olmak}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Yeni figür uygulanmasında öncelikli tercih.}   
\label{fig:yenifiguroncelik}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please make your document example minimal (remove from preamble all not to your problem relevant packages). also make your document compilable (now gives error).

Comment: just wondering where the missing percent go since they are not in area 51 or any of the Σ=99%

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid there's little to do. The package `pgf-pie` is *very badly* written.

While in a user document one can choose to use `\i` inside a `\foreach` cycle, this should ***not*** be inflicted to the users of a package, which should be as neutral as possible.

Ask the developers to change the local variables in their `\foreach` cycles.

In the meantime, add

```
\let\tikzi=\i % Fix for bad programming in pgf-pie
```

to your document preamble, just before `\begin{document}`, and in the text for a pie chart use `\tikzi` where `\i` should be used. No direct UTF-8 input, but the explicit command `\tikzi`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.9]
  \pie[
    sum=auto,
    text=legend,
    color={black!0, black!10, black!30, black!50, black!80},
    explode=0.1,
    scale font,
    before number= {\%}
  ]{%
    9/Doğru veya yanliş olduğunu umursamadan keyif almak,
    11/Çalişilan bir eş ile yapmak,
    26/Hatali da olsa akici\tikzi{} yapmak,
    2/Keyif almak,
    51/Mükemmel şekilde yapana kadar tekrar etmiş olmak
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Found an easy solution at second hour of searching. `\symbol{25}` worked for me.

Comment: Can you please add a full example called MWE so that future reader can get help from your answer?